# React - Re-arrange/swap elements in an array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm creating a simple list that I'd like to be able to "sort / rearrange" via up/down arrows, like so : https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-kilby-thcd6?file=/src/App.js

I am currently using array.splice to return my "from" item, and then once again using splice to insert the "from" item at its desired location

I can currently see this occurring "properly" in the console.logs, however I am unable to re-render my map to reflect the index positions, I have provided my map with a proper key (the ID's), and so I believe I've covered my base there.

When calling setState with my "sorted" array, I can see no visual change, and I'm looking for suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the spread operator when setting options as shown below:

```
setOptions([...newOptions]);
```

Comment: Incredible, I had not assumed that using the spread operator would have solved my issue, thank you. 

I'm curious, are you aware of why this works as opposed to setOptions(newOptions) ? To my mind, they are both producing the same array.

thanks again!

Comment: That's because of the behavior of React. It checks if the reference (aka memory address) of the `options` has changed or not in order to reflect the change in the UI. Even though your code was changing the elements but the array's reference was still the same due to which the UI was not re-rendering. In short, you were mutating the state. You can read more about it in the docs.